Using pdf-fill to fill out the fillable form makes the text shift down a little bit making the text to be cut off
When I fill out the PDF file using Preview, it perfectly shows the Text but when I use the pdf-fill on Node.js, the text gets shifted bottom few pixels and the text get cut off.
This is when I add the text using pdf-fill

This is when I add it directly using Preview.

Isthere any way that I can make it like the bottom part using pdf-fill?
